# CSS margin settings are erased when field value is changed

Tags: html, css

Each time you enter input into one or both of the fields then tab through to the next field, the input field has its margin settings completely erased, and the field shifts to the left.

Kindly shed some light on why this occurs, and please feel free to post corrections!

Here is the link to the JSfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Shadowcode/pbp4y9tu/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="login.js"></script>

<div id="left-column">
<a id="homepage-link" href="homepage.html"><img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt=" Logo" height=150px width=150px></a>
<p id="slogan">The Only Way to Escort</p>

<h2 id="login-title">Login</h2>

<form id="login-form" method="post" action="actionpage.php" autocomplete="on">

<label class="field-label" for="email">Email</label>
<input class="input-field" type=email name="email" required="required" autofocus="on">


<label class="field-label" for="password">Password</label>
<input class="input-field" type="password" name="password" required="required">
<a id="password-recovery-link" href="password-recovery.html">Forgot password?</a>

<div id="login-container"><input id="login-button" type="submit" value="Login"></div>
</form>

<p id="account">Need an account?</p>
<a id="signup-link" href="signup.html"><button id="signup-button" type="button">Sign up</button></a>

<ul id="link-list">
<li class="link-item"><a href="conditions.html">Conditions</a></li>
<li class="link-item"><a href="privacy.html">Privacy</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="billboard"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: No such thing happens when I tried it

Comment: I was able to replicate it by tabbing twice to the "Forgot Password" link. I went to examine it, re-ran the fiddle, and could not longer replicate the issue.

Comment: It's the `float: right;` on `#login-button`, but I'm at a loss for the explanation. It only happens when the screen size exceeds 1100px, which most people won't see in jsfiddle by default.

Comment: I also can't reproduce it at all in IE11 or firefox.

Comment: Hi all, indeed it seems that the problem occurs intermittently. I also tried wrapping each of the input items in a <div> container, which also seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: Not sure why my other comment isn't showing. But I changed the positioning of the login button to absolute and it solved the issue. Changes are reflected in the fiddle. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why my other comment isn't showing. But I changed the positioning of the login button to absolute and it solved the issue. Changes are reflected in the fiddle. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is because floated or absoluted positioned elements are considered out of flow elements (means they do not effect the parent div (if not a block ekement) as they are interpreted as out of its flow due to float or absolute position). In this case the `#login-container` contains the login button which has the float right property thus the button instead of confining to the login-container div takes the who left absolute colomn and the form element as its space and as its margin is auto it keeps at the place it is and effects the other elements.

Solution: There are many solutions to force a floating element to confine to respect it's parent container dimensions.

1. Use `overflow:hidden;` on the parent element (in this case #login-container). overflow:hidden actually asks the browser to however enforce the child elements to keep themselves within the container and not go out of it.
2. Using a in flow element (div or span) with the clear:both property right after the floated or out of flow element to make the parent wrap from top to the end of that in flow element. The clear:both property indicates which sides of an element's box(es) may not be adjacent to an earlier floating box. (To make this semantic you can also use pseudo element of :after to use clear:both; on the float element).
3. Using block level enforcing display like display:table on the parent will also make the floated child to conform to it's parent's dimensions.

You can use any of these solutions to fix this issue but note that this is not a bug. Its just a absense of knowledge of the workflow of elements when working with html and css.

Hope this explains the problem and helps with solutions to all who need it.